# A tag for (avoidance of) meat drying out during cooking?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Since this is *such* a common question on our site, and there are some very obvious similarities between questions on this topic, I feel like maybe it should have a tag. It's a pretty pedestrian topic but nevertheless, a tag would make it a lot easier to find and sort duplicates and also have some canonical information for "how not to overcook your food".

What do you think? Is there a culinary term for this? At first I thought "overcooking" but the trouble is that a lot of people don't realize that's what they're doing, and have to have it explained to them. We have [texture](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture) but it seems too generic for this.

Feel free to vote down if you don't think it justifies a tag (i.e. maybe we should just close these all as dupes rather than attempt to categorize them...)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer) has worked reasonably well. Maybe we just need something similar. Though writing it will be more difficult (or it'll have to be fairly general).

Seems like it'd be a misuse of tags. StackExchange seems to generally use tags to target questions to people, c.f., meta tags. So we'd ask, who is an expert in preparing meat which isn't overcooked? Well, experts in [meat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meat).

As for finding them, you can [search for multiple tags](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meat+texture). So if we tagged all such questions [meat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meat) and [texture](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture), it'd be easy to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that I don't agree with you, but that I don't think anyone who would be asking the question would be helped by the tag.

There are only 32 people on this site with the "Informed" badge for having actually read about page, for example, IIRC.

On the other hand, it would do not harm to have the tag.  It should probably be one of a family of bad-outcome or quality-problem tags.  Something like fix-dry-meat, fix-bad-coffee, fix-mushy-vegetables, just to make up some arbitrary examples.

Comment: "Avoid" seems more appropriate than "fix" for those examples: the solutions need to be pre-emptive.

Comment: People always seem to ask for fixes, when what they need is prevention.  Of course, if people actually did research, about 80% of the questions we get asked wouldn't be asked, because they are clearly answered in the first few google hits :-)

Comment: The new About page was just released a few days ago, so that number is actually high! http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/about-page-2-0-the-quickstartening/ Anyway, tags aren't really meant to help the asker, they're meant to help the readers and (potential) answerers...